# How to determine an inverse relationship of a to-one relationship using Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Is it possible in Realm to obtain the inverse relation of a to-one relationship?

For example:

```
    class Dog: Object {
        dynamic var name: String?
        dynamic var owner: Person?
    }

    class Person: Object {
        dynamic var name: String?
        let dog = LinkingObjects(fromType: Dog.self, property: "owner").first
    }



    let person = Person()
    person.name = "Harry"
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(person)
    }


    let dog = Dog()
    dog.name = "Fido"
    dog.owner = person
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(dog)
    }


    print(person.dog?.name) // -> result is nil
```

And also:

```
    let arbitraryPerson = realm.objects(Person).filter("name contains 'Harry'").first!
    let dogOwned = arbitraryPerson.dog

    print(dogOwned?.name) // -> result is nil
```

It seems that ownedDog is always `nil`. Why could the inverse relation not be determined? Or should `dog` always be of `list<T>` type (i.e. to-many relationship) to force a relation between these objects? In this situation I get it working, but it feels not correct to force a to-many relationship when it isn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `LinkingObjects` object has to be a property of your model object for Realm to know what object it goes with:

```
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var name: String?
    let _dogs = LinkingObjects(fromType: Dog.self, property: "owner")
    var dog: Dog? { return _dogs.first }
}
```

Comment: This is a very useful solution to my problem!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it, relations in Realm are not bi-directional by default, as you might be used to from Core Data. So if you want both objects to know of the relation, you have to set it both ways;

```
dog.owner = person
person.ownedDog = dog
```

Comment: That explains a lot and it works indeed! However, it is a pity that these inverse relationships are not created automatically. It is also a drawback that a primary key is required  to update the other object. Hopefully this will be improved in a future version.

Comment: Glad I could help! It's probably not on the road map to implement reverse relationships automatically. Where Core Data is mostly a way to store persistent data and it's happy to make decisions for you, Realm's goals are much closer to being a proper database. And databases often don't have automatic bi-directionality for all kinds of proper reasons.